# Getting value of variant in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, variant

Say I have a variant v defined by:

```
type value =    
    | Value of int
    | Error of string;;
```

I want to do something if v is a Value and something else if v is an Error, how can I determine this and perform different behaviors based on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the `match` expression is for:

```
match v with
| Value n -> (* Something with n *)
| Error s -> (* Something with s *)
```

(Insofar as OCaml is a functional language, it might be better to think in terms of values rather than behaviors. But OCaml can also be an imperative language if you wish.)